# Could not transfer metadata io.grpc:grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to AsposeJavaAPI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

hi i have cloned spring boot project from private remote repository, when i build it it keep giving me this warning, i want ask about the reason? and  could it affect the working ?
notice that testing the url in web browser give me 404 not found.

```java
Downloading: https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml

Could not transfer metadata io.grpc:grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to AsposeJavaAPI (https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Downloading: https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml

Could not transfer metadata io.grpc:grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml from/to AsposeJavaAPI (https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Downloading: https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/maven-metadata.xml

Could not transfer metadata com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations/maven-metadata.xml from/to AsposeJavaAPI (https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Downloading: https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/maven-metadata.xml

Could not transfer metadata io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded/maven-metadata.xml from/to AsposeJavaAPI (https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failure to transfer io.grpc:grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml from https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of AsposeJavaAPI has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata io.grpc:grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to AsposeJavaAPI (https://artifact.aspose.com/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?